# Store data in App Engine datastore from an Android app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, servlets

I have created an AppEngine connected Android application, and I'm trying to modify it to be able to store some user data on the server. I do not know what's the easiest way to do so, because I want it to be as simple as possible. I just want to store some basic data for every user. This data is: Name, Email, and some other Strings. I have created a form in the android side which will allow the user to type all the requested data, but I do not know how to send this information to the GAE server and store it in the datastore. I guess I will have to use a Servlet and some kind of RPC service to call the methods. I'm really lost because it is my first time doing this. I'm not experienced neither in android nor in web apps. I hope you can help me.

**Update**

Well, maybe I did not explain myself well. The system I've been asked to build consists on a web service that store your personal login credentials for most common sites (facebook, gmail, etc). Using a chrome extension, you ask the server for the credentials on the website you are navigating, and then the server asks to your phone for authorization. It will ask (do you give me permission to send your credentials to "some user"), and you have to ansewer yes or no and then the server will act in consequence. The point is that you have to store your credentials in the server in some way, maybe from the android app (which is what I was trying) or from somewhere else. I will also need authentication.

Pd: I use java for the server side.

Answer (score 9):

Since you already started with [AppEngine connected Android application](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_connected_android), it makes sense to continue customizing it: [App Engine Data Access: Adding Entities and RPC](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_add_rpc#data).

**Update:**

There are of course many ways to exchange data between client and server. The most simple would be a servlet handling GET and POST requests with some query parameters.

Also, most popoular lately is REST:

1. Android REST client: http://appfulcrum.com/2010/08/20/android-how-to-call-rest-service-using-asynctask/ (try using [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) instead to parse JSON)
2. Server: use a REST framework. My personal choice is [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy). An example: http://ankiewsky.blogspot.com/2010/08/resteasy-on-googleappengine-corerest.html

**Update 2:**

The simplest possible way - making/handlin a simple POST request:

1. Android client - making POST request with parameters: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient
2. Server handling POST (or GET) and extracting parameters: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet/GetReqParam.html

Comment: I will try to follow it again, but I had already tried to get it working in the past, but I did not achieve it. Is there any other way to send data from android to GAE?

Comment: Thank you for your interest, but as I said, I'm a noobie and it is hard for me to understand the information in the links you've provided. The rest client example contain some error which I cannot fix... Is there any easy example of this. I've been googling for hours but I do not find anything useful for me.

Comment: Here you go - it does not get any simpler. Note that all parameters are String. If you use other primitive types you'll need to convert them accordingly.

Comment: I have spoken to one of my professor in order to look for some additional help. He has told me that I can maybe do something like the  appengine android connected does to send information. Something involving the Authtoken and cookies. Any ideas on how to do so? I've been also cheking all the links you've given but I do not get anything working yet. I'll keep trying, thanks.

Comment: Authtoken? You never mentioned you need authentication? Anyhow this adds another layer of complexity. If I were you I'd start with the simplest example (Update2 above), make it work, and then add features.

Comment: hello @user1424490 can you please give me a detailed step by step guidance about saving and then retrieving my android app data (only "TEXT" and "REAL") to/from google appengine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Find and follow thoroughly the **Topic Index** on [this page](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-android). Gud luck